# What happen when a child process encounter a wait instruction?

Tags: c, process, fork, wait

Say I have the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv []) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0) {
        execv(*argv, argv); 
        }
    int state=0;
    wait(&state);
    return state;
}
```

Does the child simply ignore the wait and skip over since it's not the calling process?

Comment: Did you read [wait(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) and [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) -it could fail- and [execv(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execv.3.html) (which also can fail) ? Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will return `-1` and set `errno` to `ECHILD` since the child process has no children of its own to wait on. From the [wait(2) man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html):

> #### Return value
>
> - `wait()`: on success, returns the process ID of the terminated
>   child; on error, `-1` is returned.
> - ...
>
> Each of these calls sets [`errno`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) to an appropriate value in the case of an error.
>
> #### Errors
>
> - `ECHILD` (for `wait()`)
>   The calling process does not have any unwaited-for children.
> - ...

---

Note that the logic here is backwards from the norm:

> ```
> if (pid > 0) {
>     execv(*argv, argv); 
> }
> ```

Here the parent process is calling `execv()`. Usually it's the child that does so when `pid == 0`, and it's the parent that waits.